# Determine value of $a,b$ with the statements

Tags: functions

I have this statement:

> Let $f (x) = | x - a | + b$, we can determine the values ​​of $a$ and $b$,
>   if we know that:
>
> (1) The graph of the function intersects the x-axis at (-1,0) and (3,0).
>
> (2) The graph of the function intersects the y-axis in (0, -1).

My development was:

With the option $(1)$:

I have: $0 = |-(1+a)| + b$ thus $ b = -|-1-a|$ and
$0 = |3-a| + b$, thus $ b = -|3-a|$, therefore:

$|3-a| = |-1-a|$ But from here I do not know what to do.

In a [graphic view(image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV5S2.jpg), the "tip" of the function $|x|$ is $(0,0)$ and in the function $|x-a| + b$ is equal to $(1,b)$ since the function has been moved $b$ units on the y-a axis and because the midpoint of $(3,0), (1,0)$ have the same abscissa that the "tip" because the function is symmetric.

But from here I do not know what to do with these information.

With the option $(2)$:

i don't have the enough information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking it that (1) and (2) are part of the same question.

You can figure out by symmetry that $a$ is midway between $-1$ and $3$, i.e., $1.  $

[Or you could say $|3-a|=|-1-a|$ means $3-a=\pm(-1-a),$

and the only reasonable solution of that is $3-a=-(-1-a)$, i.e., $a=1$.]

Then $b$ is the value of $f(1),$ which is on the line containing $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1);$ i.e., it's $-2.$

Answer (score 0):

From $|3-a| = |-1-a|$, we have $3-a=-1-a$ or $3-a=-(-1-a)$.
First equation does not give a solution, while the second one give the solution $a=1$.

Hence $f(x)=|x-1|+b$.
From $f(0)=-1$, we get $b=-2$.